# web view causing app to crash

Tags: javascript, android, webview, titanium

Hi I have a very basic app in Titanium. There are 3 web views. When there is wifi from the start all three web views will load fine. I have a check in my code where the webview is only added if there is an internet connection. If there isn't, I add a label explaining to connect to the internet and a refresh button. When i click the refresh button, the adding of the web view crashES the app. Code works in iOS, not android. Using SDK 3.2.3. Code below:

```
refresh.addEventListener("click", function (e){
        if(Ti.Network.online){
            console.log(" here 1 -----------");
            Navbar.remove(refresh);
            console.log(" here 2 -----------");
            self.remove(NoInternet_view);
            console.log(" here 3 -----------");
            self.add(shopWebView);
            console.log(" here 4 -----------");
        }   
        else{
            alert("An internet connection is required");
        }
    });
```

The log gets to the printout "here 3 ----------" and then crashes.

Associated log:

```
F/libc    (12588): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000c (code=1), thread 12612 (KrollRuntimeThr)
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)] *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)] Build fingerprint: 'samsung/lt01wifixx/lt01wifi:4.2.2/JDQ39/T310XXUAMF1:user/release-keys'
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)] Revision: '6'
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)] pid: 12588, tid: 12612, name: KrollRuntimeThr  >>> com.girt.cuddles <<<
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)] signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0000000c
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     r0 00000000  r1 5e93c4e8  r2 000000aa  r3 00000001
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     r4 00000000  r5 5a386ec8  r6 5e49f9bc  r7 00000000
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     r8 5e49f88f  r9 5e49f870  sl 5e49f9bc  fp 5eb506a5
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     ip 5ea062f8  sp 5e49f818  lr 5e518473  pc 5e518284  cpsr 40000030
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     d0  0000000000000000  d1  4018000000000000
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     d2  0000000000000000  d3  000f4240003d0900
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     d4  0000000000000001  d5  3ff0000000000000
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     d6  0000860100000000  d7  0000860100000000
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     d16 0000000000000001  d17 0000000000000000
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     d18 0000000000004001  d19 0000000000000000
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     d20 3fc554e7eb0eb47c  d21 3e66376972bea4d0
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     d22 3f4de16b9c24a98f  d23 3fb0f4a31edab38b
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     d24 3fede16b9c24a98f  d25 3fe55559ee5e69f9
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     scr 60000013
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)] 
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)] backtrace:
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     #00  pc 00078284  /data/app-lib/com.girt.cuddles-1/libkroll-v8.so (titanium::EventEmitter::~EventEmitter()+71)
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     #01  pc 0007846f  /data/app-lib/com.girt.cuddles-1/libkroll-v8.so (titanium::JavaObject::getJavaObject()+58)
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     #02  pc 0007e157  /data/app-lib/com.girt.cuddles-1/libkroll-v8.so (titanium::TypeConverter::jsValueToJavaObject(_JNIEnv*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, bool*)+302)
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     #03  pc 0009a2f9  /data/app-lib/com.girt.cuddles-1/libkroll-v8.so (titanium::TiViewProxy::add(v8::Arguments const&)+332)
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     #04  pc 00171034  /data/app-lib/com.girt.cuddles-1/libkroll-v8.so
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     #05  pc 00067c00  <unknown>
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)] 
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)] stack:
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]          5e49f7d8  40043d5c  
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]          5e49f7f4  4094f6e4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]          5e49f7f8  00000000  
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]          5e49f7fc  59f04dc8  
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]          5e49f800  409d1c98  /system/lib/libdvm.so
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]          5e49f804  57225378  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]     #00  5e49f818  5ea06218  /data/app-lib/com.girt.cuddles-1/libkroll-v8.so
[INFO][DEBUG   ( 1764)]          ........  ........
[INFO][BootReceiver( 2125)] Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_05 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
[INFO][dumpstate(13169)] begin
[WARN][ContextImpl( 2125)] Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1346 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.broadcastEvent:291 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.processDropBoxEntry:254 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.access$100:60 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector$1.onReceive:102 
[INFO][Monitor ( 2125)] SIOP:: Current AP = 360, CP = 0
[INFO][dumpstate(13169)] done
[INFO][SurfaceFlinger( 1771)] id=71 Removed UiActivity (2/4)
[INFO][ActivityManager( 2125)] Process com.girt.cuddles (pid 12588) (adj 0) has died.
[WARN][InputDispatcher( 2125)] channel ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
[ERROR][InputDispatcher( 2125)] channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

**EDIT:** Code associated with map page:

```
var removeRefresh = function removeRefresh() {
    if(Ti.Network.getOnline()) {
        console.log("issue 1-------");
        self.remove(NoInternet_view);
        console.log("issue 2-------");
        self.add(map1);
        console.log("issue 3-------");
        Navbar.remove(refresh);
        console.log("issue 4-------");
    }
    else alert("An internet connection is required");
};
refresh.addEventListener("click", removeRefresh);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are destroying refresh (Ti.UI.Button) in an anonymous handler.

You might try this code:

```
var removeRefresh = function removeRefresh() {
    if(Ti.Network.getOnline()) {
       Ti.API.info(" Checkpoint 1 -----------");
       self.remove(NoInternet_view);
       Ti.API.info(" Checkpoint 2 -----------");
       self.add(shopWebView);
       Ti.API.info(" Checkpoint 3 -----------");
       Navbar.remove(refresh);
       Ti.API.info(" Checkpoint 4 -----------");
    }
    else alert("An internet connection is required");
};
refresh.addEventListener("click", removeRefresh);
```

You must are secured of exist NoInternet_view and shopWebView.

Titanium Studio Console will show the four messages (Ti.API.info)

Comment: I have found another issue with my code. One of my tabs is a map. I also have the internet check here. When there is no internet on start up, my two webviews and map do not appear and I add labels and refresh buttons. The webviews now will load after a connection is established and the refrsh is clicked after integrating your code..BUT if I refresh the map page FIRST and then try and refrsh either page with a webview, the app crashes. If I refresh the webview first, all is OK. Any ideas?

Comment: Code associated with the map page added to the original Question above

Comment: Are you assigning the handler "removeRefresh" each refresh page? It is important be sure of exist refresh Button. My recommendation is not remove the Refresh Button, it's better disable it in this case.

Comment: I am assigning the handler. The refresh button does exist in each page. What exactly is the reason for the crash, I don't fully understand?

Comment: I have changed all the navbar.remove(refresh0's to refresh.setVisible(false) etc. and the crash described above still occurs

Comment: Where are you adding your pages or buttons? at the same view?

Comment: I had three webviews, each had an associated window. Each window had a navbar (view) with the refresh (button) on it. I just fixed it by adding Navbar.refresh = refresh; I don't know why that even fixed it

Comment: Minimum: You should close the window before open the new window created (with the associated view added). I recommend create only one window and change the view added with the navbar (always present)